# What is the difference between 'setContext' and 'operation.setContext' when setting a custom header in Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, http-headers, apollo-client

In my React app, I have to send a custom HTTP header on every GraphQl request (when it's passing a certain condition).

I know it can be done with the [Apollo Client Link constructor](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/).

But what is the difference between `setContext` and `operation.setContext` in Apollo Client link? And when to use what?:

```
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
    // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        'X-Custom': 'Name',
      },
    };
  });
```

and this one:

```
  const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    // add the authorization to the headers
    operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => ({
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        'X-Custom': 'Name',
      },
    }));

    return forward(operation);
  });
```

What do I have to use and why?

Answer (score 0):

I am still struggling a bit on this question as well.

I made some tests and found out that my authorization header is correctly set up and sent only when using `setContext` with an async function than when using `operation.setContext` with the same async function.

Using `operation.setContext` I see the Promise get resolved in the console.log, but I am unable to find my Authorization header populated in the GraphQL query.

```
const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext(async ({ headers = {} }) => {
    const token = await getJwtToken();
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        ...(token ? { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } : {}),
      },
    };
  });

  return forward(operation);
});
```

However using `setContext` works just fine

```
const authMiddleware: ApolloLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  // add the Authorization to the headers

  const token = await getJwtToken();
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      ...(token ? { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } : {}),
    },
  };
});
```

`operation.setContext` documentation says

> Stateless links are great for implementing middleware and even network requests. The following link adds an Authorization header to every outgoing request

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/#stateless-links

but also this contradictory statement (is it related?)

> Note that this context is not included in the terminating link's request to the GraphQL server or other destination.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction#managing-context

Not sure if `operation.setContext` wouldn't work because it doesn't keep the context to the terminating link or it is just not blocking and the Promise doesn't get resolved before the Apollo sends the GraphQL request.

According to the docs `setContext`:

> The setContext function accepts a function that returns either an object or a promise, which then returns an object to set the new context of a request. It receives two arguments: the GraphQL request being executed, and the previous context. This link makes it easy to **perform the asynchronous lookup of things like authentication tokens** and more.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-context/